# state sync using useEffect for defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a tab component that accepts default value, but I have to do this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(defaultValue);
  }, [defaultValue]);
```

which I think is anti-pattern in react. How can I simply the code?

```
const Toggle = ({
  defaultValue,
  leftItem,
  rightItem,
  onValueChange,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(defaultValue);
  }, [defaultValue]);

  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <ToggleGroup
        type="single"
        value={value}
        onValueChange={(value) => {
          if (value) {
            setValue(value);
          }
        }}
      >
        <ToggleGroupItem value={leftItem.value}>
          {leftItem.label}
        </ToggleGroupItem>
        <ToggleGroupItem value={rightItem.value}>
          {rightItem.label}
        </ToggleGroupItem>
      </ToggleGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-scooby-9hwkov?file=/src/App.js:626-746

Comment: I don't think it's an anti pattern, i think it's how you should do it.

Comment: It's an anti-pattern, changes to `defaultValue` should be ignored. You are mixing controlled and uncontrolled component concept

Comment: I removed the useEffect from your code and its working so what's the problem there?
[https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-hoover-syl5ez?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark](https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-hoover-syl5ez?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Mike I need to get the selected tab value on the usage level, added more code, so the sync state is needed for that reason. https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shannon-rqzgr8

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have to control it because I need to know the selected tab on the usage level, check this version https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shannon-rqzgr8 for more code. if it's an uncontrolled tab, how the user of the component suppose to know the selected or changed tab?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-worker-md3szo?file=/src/App.js , then remove the state from the child component, you don't need it